# how to persist changes to in ml2_conf.ini file in neutron node

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, cloud, openstack

I have a single machine, all in one openstack deployment done via **conjure-up**.If i need to modify the ***ml2_conf.ini*** file in **/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini** in ***neutron-api/0*** node, a warning is displayed

```
###############################################################################
# [ WARNING ]
# Configuration file maintained by Juju. Local changes may be overwritten.
###############################################################################
```

So, the changes to this file would be lost once the neutron service is restarted. How do I make the changes permanent then?

I have Openstack 2.3.1 running on Ubuntu 16.04 Server, deployed on localhost via conjure-up. I've read some people use openstack-config but I havent been able to install that package, it doesn't seem to be available.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit Juju templates. You have to search for the folder where neutron Juju templates are saved and edit there (I do not remember exactly, but I think /var/...).
As juju is a agent-full solution, if you manually edit one config file it will remain edited only until the juju agent overwrites it. To permanently modify the file editing the template is the solution.